Can we set up an experiment in which Schrodinger's cat is hidden?
Here is a thought experiment that I would like to turn into reality.

An electron is prepared in a superposition of up and down
The electron passes through a hole into a box that is completely isolated from the rest of the universe
A device inside the box measures the spin.
If the spin is up, an alarm rings that wakes a cat and with 100% probability the cat triggers a device that emits a spin up electron from a hole at the opposite side
If the spin is down, the cat remains asleep and a spin down electron is emitted.
We then check to see if the emitted electron is in the same superposition of up and down as the initially prepared electron.

The essence of the experiment is that a hidden macro system replicates a simple quantum system that is in superposition.
My question is not about the outcome of the experiment. My question is whether any similar experiment has ever been performed.
For the purpose of this question, we do not need to involve a cat. I am happy to to have a simple electronic or mechanical macroscopic device inside the box that does the detection and preparation. However, it must leave the device in a clear measurable state if we would later open the box.
If the experiment succeeds, it means the macroscooic system was in a superposition

How would you "measure" if the electron is in a superposition? You also imply earlier that they are in definite states.

Yes, part of my question is whether this is possiblein principle. Roughly, I would measure the spin in an orthogonal direction and check if I get the same result as the initial prepared electron every time

Voting to reopen. This is a version of the "Schrodinger's cat" thought experiment, so it is definitely mainstream physics. The question is why this version will not work in the way that the questioner expects.

To test whether a system is in a superposition we would do an interference experiment. The system would be put in a superposition state, the phase of each state would be changed and then the superposed state would be recombined in a way that depends on the phase for each state. For an example see
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1929/1/012055/pdf
Now if you're doing an interference experiment and you copy information out of the interfering system then interference is suppressed:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
This process is called decoherence. Your proposed experiment copies information about the state of the electron into the cat: the cat is awake if it is spin up and asleep if it is spin down. As a result the electron will decohere and you won't see an interference effect.
There have been many experiments studying decoherence, see Section 6 in the paper I linked above for some examples.

A complementary viewpoint is that the electron and the cat are left in an entangled state, which destroys the (single-particle) superposition nature of the quantum state.

Thank you for this helpful answer. Yes, my question boils down to whether interaction with a macroscopic system that is completely hidden from me causes decoherence, or whether decoherence only occurs from a macro system connected to me in a macroscopic way. I will study the papers you linked

Using the available quantum computers of today, you could just write a program for your objective to "turn into reality" this procedure. Admittedly, given the size limitations it would still be a bit of a toy model.
Presumably the box is a quite large quantum system. But if you really could isolate
it from the rest of the universe (except the lonely electron) then the QM description
(given as a quantum computing diagram) could be roughly like this:

This is just to show the principle. The box of course requires many more than the 3 qubits that are shown, and the interactions
taking place between them (in the ellipse) could be tremendously complex. But
you definitely are allowed to have the electron interact
only once with the box (without loss of generality it's happening here through a CNOT gate).
The diagram ends just before step 6 of your question, because there you bring in "we"
that are interacting with the system so that would require an even more complicated picture.
Until that point all interactions are unitary and we know that with a pure input state
$$
  {\small\frac1{\sqrt2}}\, (|0\rangle_e + |1\rangle_e)\ |\text{in}\rangle_B
$$
where $|\dots\rangle_e$ denotes electron states and $|\dots\rangle_B$ box states, we will get some entangled total state at the output, which always has a Schmidt decomposition as:
$$
  |\text{out}\rangle_\text{Tot} =
  {\small\frac1{\sqrt2}}\, \big( |0\rangle_e\, |\psi_0\rangle_B + |1\rangle_e\, |\psi_1\rangle_B \big)
$$
Your question is if the electron is still in the same state as initially. It seems to be in
a different, entangled state. To check that, you propose to use a measurement along our original
spin axis, which was $\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\,\binom{1}{1}$, so your measurement operator is:
$${\small\frac12} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1& 1 \end{pmatrix}_{\!\large e}
\otimes \bf{1}_B
$$
Since the rest of the universe is not explicitly isolated now, decoherence will quickly make the
result a mixed state of
$$\begin{align}
  &|\text{out 0}\rangle={\small\frac1{\sqrt2}}\,  |0\rangle_e\, |\psi_0\rangle_B
  \\[5pt] \text{and}\quad
 &|\text{out 1}\rangle={\small\frac1{\sqrt2}}\,  |1\rangle_e\, |\psi_1\rangle_B
\end{align}$$
which is described by a density matrix:
$$
\rho_\text{Tot} = {\small\frac12}\, \big(|\text{out 0}\rangle\, \langle\text{out 0}|+
|\text{out 1}\rangle\, \langle\text{out 1}|\big)_\text{Tot}\ ,
$$
so that is the answer to the question what the state will be in the end.
Of course you are free then to assume that only one of those parts of the mixed state will still exists after that
point in time (if you can explain how the other one disappears, some people believe that), but the main point is that due to decoherence they
do (almost) not influence each other any more by mixing up, even if both do still exist (which is what other people believe).
Interestingly, you could of course change your question and add that when "we" observe things in step 6, we and
the box and the electron are still perfectly isolated from the rest of the universe. That would
theoretically preserve a pure state. You definitely cannot believe then that one of the components
will vanish. But this leads to an infinite regress of your question repeating
itself. I think all of this was already noticed in the ["Wigner's friend"] thought experiment...

Thank you for this very thought provoking answer. I need to think more about the points you raise and the papers in @alanf answer before accepting one of the answers


If the experiment succeeds, it means the macroscopic system was in a superposition

I'm not sure how you conclude this. When you measure the spin of the original electron at step 3, you force its spin to be either up or down - it is no longer in a superposition of up and down states. You may argue that the whole contents of the box is now in a superposition of states. But this is only true while the contents of the box remain isolated from the outside environment. Once the emitted electron is measured in step 6 then the contents of the box are no longer isolated and we know exactly what state they are in - whether the alarm went off, whether the cat is awake or asleep etc.

That is completely wrong. After step 3 the state of the whole box is an entangled  superposition of the electron and the measurement device that measured it. Nothing is "forced" to be different than that. (You may subsequently have decoherence, but even then it becomes a mixed state, not forced into a simpler one as you propose.)

@JosBergervoet Good point - I have modified my answer.

Yes, step 6 does it... (But still we would have to look at what exactly the state after that step is, to answer OP's question... Maybe I'll give it a try!)

Thank you for your answer, however the idea is not to measure at the end if it is up or down, but to perform the experiment many times and measure the spin in an orthogonal direction and check we get the same result each time (or possibly a better aproach to be found in papers linked in @alanf's answer

The idea is that I don't make a measurement at step 3. At this stage of the experiment it is the same as Schrodinger's cat experiment

Perhaps I forgot to make this clear in my answer, but it is well-known that for an entangled state as we have at the end, changing to spin measurment on any other axis will still give you the mixed state with the two answers. You can't undo entanglement by only looking at the electron at a special angle! So you will definitely not find the electron repeatedly in a specific prefered state if you do this many times, whatever you choose for that preferred state...

Thank you, am I right this id due to decoherence in the mixed state? Your comment probably provides a nuce succinct answer to my question if so
